# React native createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I am trying to createBottomTabNavigator but I am getting this following error

***Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `BottomTabNavigator`.
in BottomTabNavigator (at AppRoot.js:76)***

here is my code

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
// stacks
const StackApp = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SplashScreen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Log_In"
        component={Log_In}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Sign_Up"
        component={Sign_Up}
        options={{
          title: "Create Account",
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#fcf5f3" },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SplashScreen"
        component={SplashScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="UserResetPassword" component={UserResetPassword} />
      <Stack.Screen name="UserProfileScreen" component={UserProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="EditeProfileScreen" component={EditeProfileScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};


export default function AppTabs() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={StackApp} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this the complete code, and you should trying solving your problem first using the error message before seeking help.

Comment: I tried many times. but I did not reach anything

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in the the `react-navigation/bottom-tabs` version `6.0.2` regarding the `createBottomTabNavigator()` function.

Downgrade the version `5.11.13` and it will fix the issue for you. I had the same problem today and downgrading worked fine.